# How to controll position of a FeeTech FS90 RC Servo motor using a Mitsubishi FX5U PLC?

Tags: plc

I want to control the position of a FeeTech FS90 RC Servo motor using a Mitsubishi FX5U PLC. The datasheet for the FS90 can be accessed through this link: https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1435/FS90-specs.pdf The datasheet for the FX5U can be found in this link: http://www.atronika.com/Mitsubishi/PLC/MITSUBISHI_manual_plc_fx5_users.pdf

Please help me with how can I control position of the FS90 using the PLC?

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. What have you implemented so far?

Comment: That's a "servo actuator". The motor is a simple DC motor but the whole device consists of PWM receiver, motor driver, actuator mechanism and feedback potentiometer. A servo motor usually refers to a motor an encoder combination as, typically, used in industrial applications such as CNC machines or robots.

Answer (score 0):

You can't without some additional hardware.

*Table 1. The servo actuator control specification.*

[image]

The position of the servo actuator you have chosen is controlled by pulse-width modulation with 900 μs being fully anti-clockwise and 2100 μs being fully clockwise.

*Table 2. The PLC analogue output specification.*

[image]

The PLC analogue output will be 0 to 10 V or 4 to 20 mA. Place generally don't do PWM.

To have the PLC control the servo actuator you will need some hardware that converts 0 - 10 V analogue to the required PWM control signal for the servo actuator.

[image]

*Figure 1. A sample RC-servo actuator PWM control scheme. Source: [Berkeley.edu](http://courses.me.berkeley.edu/ME102B/lab4.html).*